# about return syntax in c#

Tags: c#

I wonder why I need to put return syntax twice time in below code,

```
public string test(){
 bool a = true;
 if(a){
   string result = "A is true";
 }else{
   string result = "A is not true";
 }

  return result;
}
```

it makes an error that say The name 'result' does not exist in the current context.

but either way, there is the result variable. Hmm..

So I changed the code like this,

```
public string test(){
 bool a = true;
 if(a){
   string result = "A is true";
   return result;
 }else{
   string result = "A is not true";
   return result;
 }
}
```

Then it works. Is it correct using like this?

please advice me,

Thank you!

Comment: I very much doubt that your second code *actually* works. You haven't declared the variable `result` at any point. Note that none of this has anything to do with ASP.NET - it's just C#.

Comment: You say "then it works," but even your second piece of code is not valid C# unless `result` is declared elsewhere.  Are you sure it works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are just missing the declaration of `result` in the code blocks.. personally I would suggest the second code block anyway (when corrected) but here...

```
public string test(){
 bool a = true;
 string result = string.Empty;
 if(a){
   result = "A is true";
 }else{
   result = "A is not true";
 }

  return result;
}
```

And if you were going to go with the second block you could simplify it to:

```
public string test(){
 bool a = true;
 if(a){
   return "A is true";
 }else{
   return "A is not true";
 }
}
```

Or further to:

```
public string test(){
 bool a = true;

 return a ? "A is true" : "A is not true";
}
```

And several other iterations of similar code (string formatting etc).

Comment: You don't even need to initialise `result`.